Can't connect Nifi to Elasticsearch 8.X version with PutElasticsearchHttp
I'm experimenting with a small pipeline that gets data from postgres and moves it to elasticsearch. It was working well with elasticsearch 7.4.0 by using the PutElasticsearchHttp processer. (all running on docker for windows containers)
But now I am using elasticsearch verion 8.7.1 and I don't get it to work anymore. I tried several different connection urls but none of them seem to work. Does anyone know how to get it to connect to elasticsearch 8.7.1?
Nifi:

PutElasticsearchHttp processer:

yml file (elasticserach):
version: "3.7"
services:
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.7.1
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - network.host= 0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536


  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.7.1
    container_name: kibana
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch:9200
    ports:
      - 5601:5601


have you got access to the elastic log files?

Yes, I got access to the logs. Running the Nifi flow doesn't seem to add any log.
Last entry in log file:
"log.level": "INFO",  "current.health":"GREEN", "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS", "event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server", "process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[4db01df791e5][masterService#updateTask][T#1]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.cluster.routing.allocation.AllocationService", "elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"VWyXQXK9S9m2MRa-bf3rhA", "elasticsearch.node.id":"HIQ6bvqWRGaDfgsxg5MfLA", "elasticsearch.node.name":"4db01df791e5", "elasticsearch.cluster.name":"docker-cluster"}

i see. if possible, try to save the response the nifi processor receives. it should look something like this (on the right)

This i got from the nifi logs: 2024-06-02 20:42:58 2024-06-02 18:42:58,742 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-2] o.a.n.p.e.PutElasticsearchHttp PutElasticsearchHttp[id=b8cb2396-018f-1000-202c-ef923a97d77e] Elasticsearch returned code 400 with message Bad Request, transferring flow file to failure

Is Kibana is working fine ? Or so to say can kibana connect to elasticsearch ? I am suspecting http/https ? As by default elasticsearch 8.x will run with self generated certificate if I remember well

Yes Kibana 8.X and elasticsearch 8.X are working. I made the same pipeline in airflow (postgres->elastic) and I can see the postgres data in Kibana. Using http

I meant, try to capture the HTTP response from elastic. something like this.  Also, use PutElasticsearchJson  as PutElasticsearchHttp is deprecated. then, if that doesn't solve it, turn on Output Error Responses or Log Error Responses, and post the output.

@Yarin_007 Yes, you are right. Changed the processor to one I have available in my Nifi version (PutElasticsearchRecord) and now it does work. Thanks

I found a working solution by using the PutElasticsearchRecord processor instead of the deprecated  PutElasticsearchHttp processor.
HTTP Host in controller set to (http://IP Adress:port): http://127.0.0.1:9200
Processor settings:

